# VPN DNS configuration bug in OS X

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I am using TunnelBlick to connect to an VPN (OpenVPN) with OS X 10.9.2. I can authenticate and pass traffic but the DNS entries injected from the VPN do not work.

Here is the output of `scutil --dns` (resolver #1 is the correct DNS server injected by Tunnelblick)

```
resolver #1
  search domain[0] : XXXXX.net
  nameserver[0] : 10.10.0.15
  if_index : 5 (en1)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

The problem is `if_index` should be `tap0` and not `en1`. From `ifconfig`:

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether e4:ce:8f:1b:42:cc
    inet6 fe80::e6ce:8fff:fe1b:42cc%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
    inet 10.0.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

tap0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:83:8d:37:dc:b9
    inet 10.10.0.100 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 10.10.255.255
    open (pid 4997)
```

`nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` all can reach the DNS server correctly but the rest of OS X cannot (I understand these have a standalone resolution mechanism that do not rely on the rest of OS X). I have confirmed with Wireshark that the DNS packets sent by `nslookup` et. al. go out `tap0` and DNS packets sent by other programs (eg `ping`) go out `eth0` and of course never get to their destination. Could it be possible that `scutil` doesn't actually look at the routing table before sending packets?? If so how can I edit the scutil entry to correct the `if_index`?

Tunnelblick is configuration drop down is set for `set nameserver` and the relevant portion of my server.conf is shown below. Since I am getting the DNS information correctly I think the problem is with OS X and its scutil setup.

```
...etc..

server-bridge 10.10.0.15 255.255.0.0 10.10.0.100 10.10.0.200

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.10.0.15"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN wattsworth.net"

...etc...
```

Comment: Please include your Tunnelblick configuration and the OpenVPN server configuration...  You should have a `push "dhcp-option DNS ..."` statement server-side, and in the Tunnelblick config "set nameserver" for the `'Set DNS/WINS'` drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with the same problem, I found that running [`scselect`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scselect.8.html) command with `new-location-name` set to the same as currently used did reset the network settings and DNS started working through VPN.

At the same time `scutil` results remained constant (i.e. it shows the `if_index` set to the Ethernet interface).

First run `scselect` with no arguments to learn the GUID of currently used location, then again with the intended location as an argument.